# correct tense: will lend you money OR have lent you money

Tags: tense

I have made up the sentences below.

(1) I have helped a lot. **(AFTER YOU GIVE SOME MONEY TO YOUR FRIEND, YOU SAY)** This is the last time I have lent you money.

(2) **(Same scenario as above)** This is the last time I will lend you money.

I am not which tense of "lend" fits in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering because I can't comment yet. I am 99% sure (1) is not correct. You can say (2) in most cases, but you can also say "this is the last time I lend you money."

The first one is incorrect because it is more of a given fact. Since the word "last" can be used in place of recent, you are essentially saying "This is the most recent time I have lent you money." Going into the past tense in this sentence essentially implies this meaning of last, because you are basically 'looking into the past.'

"This is the last time I lend you money" is essentially short for "This is the last time I perform the act of lending you money" - and the same goes for your given sentence (2). Both can be used interchangeably, as I believe (at least colloquially) that the "will" does not make much of a difference.

Comment: Since you're posting this as an answer anyway, can you tell why you think the first sentence is incorrect, and why your alternative is also valid?